# Support density distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a distribution function $F$ with associated density $f$. Consider two sets:

1. $S_1=\{s: F(s+\varepsilon)> F(s-\varepsilon)\;\forall\;\varepsilon>0\}$;
2. $S_2=cl(\{s: f(s)>0\})$.

Is $S_1=S_2$?

I am asking this because both sets seem to be defined as the support of a random variable.

Comment: That depends : what kind of regularity do you assume on $f$? if none (but integrability), you may always change $f$ on a set of measure $0$, without modifying $F$...if $f$ is continuous (even piecewise), then you can prove your claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of the equivalence of the two definitions assuming that a continuous density $f$ exists: suppose $c$ is in the closure of $\{s: f(s) >0\}$. Let $\epsilon >0$. We have to show that $F(c+\epsilon)-F(c-\epsilon)>0$. Of course, $F(c+\epsilon)-F(c-\epsilon)\geq 0$. If possible, let $F(c+\epsilon)-F(c-\epsilon)=0$. Then $\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon} f(s)ds=0$. Since $f$ is continuous and non-negative this implies $f(s)=0$ whenever $s \in (c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$. Hence this interval contains no point of the set $\{s: f(s) >0\}$ and this is a contradiction.

Conversely, suppose $F(c+\epsilon)-F(c-\epsilon)>0$ for all $\epsilon >0$. Consider the interval $(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$. If this interval contains no point of the set $\{s: f(s) >0\}$ then $f(s)=0$ for all $s$ in this interval and this makes $F(c+\epsilon)-F(c-\epsilon)=\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon} f(s)ds=0$. This is a contradiction, so the interval $(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$ must intresect the set $\{s: f(s) >0\}$ for every $\epsilon >0$. This implies that $c$ is in the closure of $\{s: f(s) >0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

under assumption that F is continuous and non-decreasing (it's distribution) and differentable (has density F'(x) = f(x))

$\forall \epsilon>0 \forall s\in \mathbb{R}:  F(s+\epsilon) - F(s - \epsilon) > 0 <=> f(s) > 0$

thus 
$S_1 =S_2$